# Best way to Pass Typescript Date property as a parameter to a Web Api 2.0 method

Tags: c#, typescript, datetime, angular5, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a date picker in html which is bound to a Date property of an employee.

ex: i have selected the date as "Thu Feb 22 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)".this is the value i get when i log in console.

But when i tried to debug in C# the value is changed.
{21-02-2018 18:30:00}

How to handle or work with the typescript date object when passing it to a API method and displaying it back

My typescript Model

```
export class Visitor {
    public id: number;
    public firstname: string;
    public lastname: string;
    public dob: Date;
    public genderId: number;
    public age: number;
}
```

and C# model

```
 public class Visitor
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }


        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use moment.js to handle dates in front-end and when you send back to back-end try the same.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are passing a valid `Date` object you should be fine.

Your problem probably lies in your Culture settings in .NET side.
Can you please try doing this in your controller action:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("gu-IN");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
```

Since you provide no code, this is merely a guess.

Answer (score 0):

When you are printing in console, browser is printing the date in local timezone which is India in your case. When you are retrieving the value on server, C# is treating date in UTC. That is why you see a difference of 5.30 hours. India time is UTC + 5.30 Hours.

If you are storing the date value in UTC format on server side then convert the value of date object from client side to UTC using the libraries such as momentjs. 
While retrieving the value from server, send the UTC value from server and convert it to local time zone using libraries such as momentjs. I think this strategy will work.